# Why does the lat and lon dimension in nc file change from assembling two nc files?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have two `.nc` files, which have similar lat and lon dimensions, CRS and everything else.

```
Dimensions:  (lat: 62, lon: 94)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 58.46 58.79 59.12 59.44 ... 77.45 77.78 78.11 78.44
  * lon      (lon) float64 -150.0 -149.4 -148.9 -148.3 ... -98.56 -98.0 -97.43
```

When I then add these two files together, the whole dimension changes:

```
dem = xr.open_dataset(path + 'DEM.nc')
dc = xr.open_dataset(path + 'DC.nc')

X = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(-2.2432e+01 + (dem.Band1 * 1.97521e-06) + (dc.Band1 * 5.97414e-04))))

print(X)

<xarray.DataArray 'Band1' (lat: 11, lon: 94)>
  * lat      (lat) float64 65.01 65.34 65.67 65.99 ... 73.52 74.18 77.78 78.44
  * lon      (lon) float64 -150.0 -149.4 -148.9 -148.3 ... -98.56 -98.0 -97.43
```

What happens? Why does this addition change the whole dimension?

NB. the `dc` file has some grid cells without data `nan`. Does that influence it?

EDIT: With the answer given, I still do not think it is purely because of missing data, look at the image of the datasets individually and the datasets combined:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide shape of both datasets? And maybe provide test data to rebuild this problem.

Comment: Upload to drive or whatever and provide a public link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the answer to yourself with

`the dc file has some grid cells without data nan. Does that influence it?`
Yes because xarray is looking to the coordinates too instead of just doing vectorized operations. Check out the documentation to find out more about it.

The work around is very simple: Let numpy do the job for you!

```
X = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(-2.2432e+01 + (dem.Band1.values * 1.97521e-06) + (dc.Band1.values * 5.97414e-04))))

data_array = xarray.DataArray(X, coords={'lat': dem.lat, 'lon': dem.lon}, dims=['lat', 'lon'])

dem['combined'] = data_array
```

Comment: Hi @dl.meteo.
I do not think that is really the case. I have edited my question, do you have time to look it over again with the image of the individual datasets and the combined? Thank you.

Comment: @Thomas check out my updated answer. I think this is a suitable work around for you. Please rate my answer if it fits to your requirements.

Comment: I will have a look at it right now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work nicely. Beautiful - thanks!